I'm getting 17 children of an initial_fen string where it should be 33 of them. A Python dictionary recursive generation
Why this short code doesn't generate, say, this position 7k/8/4Q3/8/8/8/6K1/8 b - -:
from this initial one:
initial_fen = "7k/8/4Q3/8/8/8/5K2/8 w - - 0 1"
import chess

def simplify_fen_string(fen):
    parts = fen.split(' ')
    simplified_fen = ' '.join(parts[:4])
    return simplified_fen

def create_AR_entry(fen, parent):
    return {
        'fen': fen,
        'parent': parent,
        'children': [],
        'result': None,
        'sequence': [],
        'to_end': None,
        'processed': None
    }

def evaluate_position(board):
    if board.is_checkmate():
        return 1000 if board.turn == chess.BLACK else -1000
    elif board.is_stalemate() or board.is_insufficient_material() or board.can_claim_draw():
        return 0
    return None

def generate_positions(board, AR, parent_fen, visited, counter):
    current_fen = simplify_fen_string(board.fen())
    if current_fen in visited:
        return
    visited.add(current_fen)

    counter['count'] += 1
    if counter['count'] % 10000 == 0:
        print(f"Prohledáno {counter['count']} pozic.")

    if current_fen not in AR:
        AR[current_fen] = create_AR_entry(current_fen, parent_fen)
    entry = AR[current_fen]

    if entry['processed'] is None:
        entry['result'] = evaluate_position(board)
        entry['to_end'] = 0 if entry['result'] is not None else None
        entry['processed'] = True

    if parent_fen and parent_fen in AR:
        AR[parent_fen]['children'].append(current_fen)

    if entry['result'] is None:
        for move in board.legal_moves:
            board.push(move)
            generate_positions(board, AR, current_fen, visited, counter)
            board.pop()

def main():
    initial_fen = "7k/8/4Q3/8/8/8/5K2/8 w - - 0 1"
    board = chess.Board(initial_fen)
    AR = {}
    visited = set()
    counter = {'count': 0}
    generate_positions(board, AR, None, visited, counter)

    initial_entry = AR[simplify_fen_string(initial_fen)]
    print("Result for initial position:", initial_entry['result'])
    print("To end:", initial_entry['to_end'])
    print("Final number of children:", len(initial_entry['children']))
    for child_fen in initial_entry['children']:
        child_entry = AR[child_fen]
        print(f"Child: {child_fen}, Result: {child_entry['result']}, To end: {child_entry['to_end']}")

main()

It gives this output: instead of correct 33 positions it yields 17 only
Final number of children: 17
Prohledáno 10000 pozic.
Prohledáno 20000 pozic.
Prohledáno 30000 pozic.
Prohledáno 40000 pozic.
Prohledáno 50000 pozic.
Prohledáno 60000 pozic.
Prohledáno 70000 pozic.
Prohledáno 80000 pozic.
Prohledáno 90000 pozic.
Prohledáno 100000 pozic.
Prohledáno 110000 pozic.
Prohledáno 120000 pozic.
Prohledáno 130000 pozic.
Prohledáno 140000 pozic.
Prohledáno 150000 pozic.
Prohledáno 160000 pozic.
Prohledáno 170000 pozic.
Prohledáno 180000 pozic.
Prohledáno 190000 pozic.
Prohledáno 200000 pozic.
Prohledáno 210000 pozic.
Prohledáno 220000 pozic.
Prohledáno 230000 pozic.
Result for initial position: None
To end: None
Final number of children: 17
Child: 6Qk/8/8/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 4Q2k/8/8/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 2Q4k/8/8/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/5Q2/8/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: 0, To end: 0
Child: 7k/8/7Q/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/5Q2/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/2Q5/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/Q7/8/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/5Q2/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/4Q3/8/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/8/4Q3/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/8/2Q5/8/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/8/8/7Q/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/8/8/4Q3/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/8/8/1Q6/5K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/8/8/8/4QK2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None
Child: 7k/8/8/8/8/8/Q4K2/8 b - -, Result: None, To end: None

